# How to create a nested list for N number of unique IDs and name in python?

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

Create a Python program to accept N Names and unique IDs for the
names entered to create nested list one with name and other with IDs,
When repeated value for the ID is entered by the user it should be
asking to enter the new value which is not repeated.

my code should be in this format:
[name1:ID1,name2:ID2.....Nname:NID]

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand why you are using nested list to make this approach. the best way is to use python dictionaries which is easier to implement. but anyway, here is how you get your task done.

```
n = int(input("input the number of names: "))
details = []
ids = []
i = 0
for i in range(n):
    name = input("Name: ")
    Id = input("Id: ")
    while Id in ids:
        print("Please enter unique id for",name)
        Id = input("Id: ")
    ids.append(Id)
    details.append([name,Id])

for i in details:
    print(i)
```

the square brackets around the `name` and `Id` (in Ln12) create the list containing `name` and `Id` and then the `append()` function appends this list to the details list. this is how nested list is made